# Combining Fluid Simulation and Rigid Body Physics: How to melt a falling object?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

Hello Blender Community,

I am attempting to design an object that falls onto a surface, at which point it will begin melting (via a fluid simulation at low speed and high viscosity). I want the object to fully maintain its form until it comes into contact with the surface.

As it stands, I have attempted this design with multiple layers. On layer one is the rigid body object falling onto the surface. On layer two is the exact same object with a fluid simulation applied. As it stands, I have merely switched the layers rendered during the rendering process to simulate the desired effect, but I'm not entirely satisfied with the result. Is there a better way to go about my design?

Comment: I think that's pretty much what you'll have to do. Whether you end up animating visibility, layers, whatever, you'll have to swap the rigid body with the fluid at some point..

Comment: [Duplicate of this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6947/935)

Comment: Try using animation drivers to control the start of the fluid simulator using the distance of the fluid object, i.e. if it is 0-ish, multiply the current frame with the frame rate.