# Problems with an animation

Tags: animation

I'm newly started with Blender, and happy with it so far. I am doing some simple animation, with a simple character flying through the air and hitting a big sphere, and what I want is for the character to disappear and a shape which looks a bit like goo to appear on the sphere where the character landed. I have been looking for a couple of hours with no luck, if someone could point me into the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: This could work with dynamic paint http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Dynamic_Paint

Comment: [similar to this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6947/935)

Answer (score 1):

To address the goo goal.

(01) Fluid Particles

This link

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics

[Fluid Particles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics)

(02) Some mesh animated using Wave Modifier and or Armature.

(03) Particles

(04) Fluid Simulation

Most preferred listed at top.  Suit to your tastes.

... Some would have dynamic 3D gravity qualities.

Some video sites have video instruction on these topics.

You stated you are "newly started".  Please assume that the above is work the first time .. but not too much work.  It might be a lot of work for some other people.